Missing email headers and DKIM check
Suppose the DKIM-Signature of an arriving email has this parameter:
h=from:to:junk:subject:date;

And suppose the header junk is missing but everything else including alignment is in order with DKIM.
Will the email message pass DKIM or not?
In other words, will the missing header be considered empty and signed that way or will it trigger failure?

The fields after the "h" are all the fields that have been signed.  If "junk" isn't there, then it was added and wasn't part of the signed fields.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail#Technical_details

@michaelt Do you mean it "wasn't" added? and so will DKIM pass? The wikipedia article states: "A non-existing field matches the empty string, so that adding a field with that name will break the signature". so if the header is not added, does it pass DKIM?

It's going to use the signature in the of the hash value of the header fields, since it's missing one of the required fields, it should lead to a verification error. It's not entirely clear when the junk field gets stripped, if it happens after the email is delivered, it may not matter.  For absolute clarity, it would be good  to see it fail/succeed either in logs or in a testing tool.

yes, checked some DKIM source codes and did some testing. seems like a proper MTA is programmed to recognize a number of headers to concat and sign. it checks an outgoing message and if a header is missing it won't be included in the h list. if a header is there and the MTA recognizes it, then its name:value is added to the data to sign and also its name is added to the h list before the message is dispatched. so the message cited in my post with 'junk' in h would fail the DKIM test.
